# Changing DNNFriendlyUrl urlFormat to "advanced" from "humanfriendly" causes redirect loop

Tags: url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, friendly-url

### Background

Our server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with IIS 7.5.

Yesterday, we updated a site from DNN 7.3.1 to 7.4. Ever since then, links will only work with a `.aspx` on the end of them. For example, `http://www.example.com/Download.aspx` works, but `http://www.example.com/Download` will return a 404 error. This has only happened since updating to 7.4. The extensions URLs worked before the update.

Googling took me to [this wiki page](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/activating-advanced-url-management) which recommended changing the `urlFormat` of the `DNNFriendlyUrl` entry in web.config from `human friendly` to `advanced`, i.e.

```
<add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="advanced" />
```

### Problem

Making this change as recommended causes an infinite redirect loop:

[image: Infinite redirect loop]

This happens on any URL we try to load, with or without the `.aspx` extension.

### What I've tried

The wiki page linked above noted that a prerequisite to activating advanced URL management was the installation of [hotfix 980368](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368), which would not install on our server. [A Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/317600/cant-install-kb-980368-the-update-is-not-applicable-to-your-computer) suggests this is because we have Service Pack 1 installed.

Comment: Whenever you're dealing with a redirect loop, it's important to determine what the nature of the loop is.

The first thing is to determine whether or not you are getting a 302 redirect or a 301 redirect.

This can be checked using Fiddler or by looking at the 'Network' tab in browser tools, to see what the http status code responses are.

When using 'advanced' mode in DNN 7.1 and later, any redirect issued by the Url Rewriting will also issue a 'x-url-redirect-reason' response header, which will give a clue.